# A Way To Store Unknown Amount Of Separate Lists As Columns In A csv File (Python)?

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, dictionary

So, I am writing a program that takes user input of four variables in my list: [full_name, first_time, second_time, third_time]. I need to be able to take my list or dictionary, (which ever one is easier?) and have multiple stored lists that then transfer into my csv file named "times.csv" .

This program is meant for a coach to record his athletes running times. I know I can use things like .update and .append to add to one list but I do not know enough about csv files, lists, and programming in general to know how to take user input and store said (separate) lists into a csv file, without replacing the first user inputted column/list.

Maybe some kind of for loop in the writer section of my code??

code below:

```
import csv
file_name = 'times.csv'

true = 'yes'

while true:
    user_entry = input("Do you want an entry? 'yes' to continue, ('no' to stop): ")
    if user_entry == 'no':
        break
    else:
        full_name = input("Enter a full name: ") 
        first_time = float(input("Enter first time: "))
        second_time = float(input("Enter second time: "))
        third_time = float(input("Enter third time: "))
    list1 = [full_name, first_time, second_time, third_time]
    print(list1)
with open(file_name, 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    fields = next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:
        list1.append(row)

print(', '.join(field for field in fields))


with open(file_name, 'w') as csv_file:

    write_to_file = csv.writer(csv_file)
    write_to_file.writerow(list1)
```

Comment: maybe use `pandas` to read `csv`  and keep it as `DataFrame` - it has many function to work with data and it can be more useful then writing all code from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Step 1: Create file csv file if not already exist
Step 2: Read the csv file to memory
Step 3: Get the user input and append to the data you read from the csv ( can be looped if there are multiple entries to be read)
Step 4: Write back the data (not append but as new file with the same name)
```

Implementation:

```
from pathlib import Path
import csv


def read_existing_data(filename):
    csv_file = Path(filename)
    csv_file.touch(exist_ok=True)
    input_data = [row for row in csv.DictReader(open(filename))]
    return input_data


def get_user_input():
    entry_list = list()
    entry = dict()
    true = 'yes'

    while true:
        user_entry = input("Do you want an entry? 'yes' to continue, ('no' to stop): ")
        if user_entry == 'no':
            break
        else:
            entry["full_name"] = input("Enter a full name: ")
            entry["first_time"] = float(input("Enter first time: "))
            entry["second_time"] = float(input("Enter second time: "))
            entry["third_time"] = float(input("Enter third time: "))
        entry_list.append(entry)
    return entry_list


def save_to_file(filename, csv_data):
    columns = csv_data[0].keys()
    try:
        with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=columns)
            writer.writeheader()
            for rows in csv_data:
                writer.writerow(rows)
    except IOError:
        print("I/O error")


file_name = "times.csv"
# Read Existing data
data = read_existing_data(file_name)
# Append new data
data.extend(get_user_input())
# Save to file
save_to_file(file_name, data)
```